# Python search string match from line then print few columns

Tags: python

Large text file with 1 million records

i would like to search for a matching string,(e.g 2580552) from file and print from those lines fields in the 1st, 5th, and 45th and 46th columns, using awk i capture data, but need answer in python.

```
grep 2580552 /tmp/myfile.txt |awk -F'\t' '$5 == "2580552" {print $1","$5 $41","$46}'
```

Thx, 
Sai.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. You say you “need answer in python”. So what's preventing you from doing this? Do you have Python installed? Do you know anything about Python at all? Can you open a file in Python?

Comment: Yes, python installed and i know python some level but i never tried this solution.  Here is what i tried and found somewhat solution.                        #!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                 with open("/tmp/test.txt", "r") as fname:
     for line in fname:
         line = line.split()
         print(line[2], line[6])
    # OR
         print(line[2], line[-1])

Answer (score 0):

This code help me resolve the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
pattern = r'15686547'
with open('/tmp/some_junk_test.txt', 'rU') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            a = line.split('\t')
            if str(a[4]) == pattern:
                print(a[0], a[4], a[40], a[45])
            else:
                print("Failed to find match % s" % pattern)`
```